# Expanded Security Maintenance is not enabled on Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, software-updates

Upon SSH'ing into my Ubuntu MATE 22.04 machine, I am greeted with:

> Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

in

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-60-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

...

7 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm
```

What is that, and if I wanted, how do I enable it?

Comment: what that is should be explained at the link at the end of your output.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is still in regular support, why would you even enable ESM? Has Ubuntu started to take users hostage with security updates? If that's the case, it'd be a very good point in time to switch to a distro that doesn't claim a release is still in regular support when it actually requires you to register to get security updates. I don't understand Canonical, this leaves **such** a bad taste in my mouth.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is free for personal purposes for up to 5 Ubuntu running devices.

---

I did visit https://ubuntu.com/esm and as I have a Canonical Ubuntu account already, I logged into https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard

It now generated a TOKEN:

Machine type: Physical
Machines: 5
Active machines: 0
Token: <30-char string>

---

To actually use it, your Ubuntu machine must have `ubuntu-advantage-tools` installed:

```
apt install ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

Copy the TOKEN into the clipboard, and run:

```
sudo pro attach <TOKEN above>
```

Which should automatically attach your machine to your Canonical (Pro) Ubuntu account:

```
Enabling default service esm-apps
Updating package lists
Ubuntu Pro: ESM Apps enabled
Enabling default service esm-infra
Updating package lists
Ubuntu Pro: ESM Infra enabled
Updating 'livepatch' on changed directives.
Disabling Livepatch prior to re-attach with new token
Canonical livepatch enabled.
Unable to determine current instance-id
This machine is now attached to 'Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription'

SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION
esm-apps         yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
livepatch        yes       enabled   Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel  yes       disabled  Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated

NOTICES
Operation in progress: pro attach

Enable services with: pro enable <service>

     Account: <EMAIL REDACTED>
Subscription: Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription
```

It also should now be glowing green for the enabled stuff and red for the disabled.

[image]

I rebooted after about 10 minutes since... I then ran `apt upgrade` to see new updates.

Comment: But what is it? This only answers half the question. The link (https://ubuntu.com/esm) doesn't seem to cover "Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications", only says security updates for the Universe repo are continued after end of standard support, but 22.04 is still in standard support, so that seems to be a separate feature.

Comment: [This post on Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com/questions/1452497/what-are-esm-apps-and-how-do-they-relate-to-ubuntu-pro) and the [Ubuntu Pro page](//ubuntu.com/pro) explain it better. ESM Apps offers security updates for Universe, where Canonical didn't used to provide that at all, now they do for 10 years.

Answer (score -2):

Ubuntu Pro was previously named Expanded Security Maintenance (esm). It provides an SLA for security fixes for the entire distribution (‘main and universe’ packages) for ten years.

Ubuntu LTS (without Pro) consists of five years of security updates for packages in the Ubuntu Main repository, and best-effort security coverage for everything else like the Ubuntu Universe repository (since 2006).

There are two streams in Pro.
The Ubuntu Main repository is called 'esm-infra' in Pro.
The Ubuntu Universe repository  is called 'esm-apps' in Pro.
The “esm-infra” stream covers ‘Main’ packages for the period after the standard five year security maintenance. We call this ‘infra’ because it is commonly used to build Ubuntus private cloud, storage and kubernetes clusters.
The “esm-apps” stream covers all ‘Universe’ packages for ten years from the release of the LTS. ‘Universe’ packages are not typically deployed.

What vulnerabilities get fixed?
Ubuntu Security Team prioritises critical and high [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/)s. They will also tackle selected medium CVEs. For customers with specific compliance requirements, Canonical allows enterprise customers to sponsor additional patches up to medium CVEs for a selected subset of packages and their dependencies.

Canonical (the organization behind the Ubuntu distribution of Linux) doesn’t withhold those commercially “sponsored” security updates. Pro is free for personal use. Canonical secured more and more Universe Packages via such enterprise customer engagements. Now they cover the full set of packages in ‘Universe’.

APT shows updates that are immediately installable, as well as updates that are available with an Ubuntu Pro subscription. These would be updates for packages in ‘Main’ after the standard five year period, or ‘Universe’ updates that are not in the best-effort or community-provided set.
The message is only displayed when you are using packages for which there are security fixes in Ubuntu Pro, and it gives you the exact list of packages that are affected on your system.

Ubuntu LTS security updates are unchanged - free security support coverage for either ‘Main or Universe’ packages. An Ubuntu Pro subscription offers additional security patches, which Ubuntu LTS has never provided before.

How to enable Pro on you installation of Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo pro attach <token>
```

You can get up to five free tokens for personal use by registering at:

> https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard